# Merge jpg from diffrerent subdirectories individually and save them to a single folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have folders named from 1 to 700 in a directory(There are lots of missing numbers in between). In each of the folder there are `jpg` files that need to be merged and converted to `pdf` files. The images in each folder has to be created as a seperate `pdf` file. For merging and converting the images I have used the following script:

```
cd subfolder1
for i in *.jpg; do num=`expr match "$i" '\([0-9]\+\).*'`;
padded=`printf "%03d" $num`; mv -v "$i" "${i/$num/$padded}"; done
FILES=$( find . -type f -name "*jpg" | cut -d/ -f 2)
mkdir temp && cd temp 
for file in $FILES; do 
    BASE=$(echo $file | sed 's/.jpg//g');
    convert ../$BASE.jpg $BASE.pdf; 
    done && 
pdftk *pdf cat output ../../pdffolder/subfolder1.pdf && 
cd .. 
rm -rf temp
```

`pdffolder` is the directory where I need all the pdf files to be in. Is there something like `for directory in a` or something that I can use for this purpose? The `pdf` file has to be the same name as that of the subfolder as well. Operating platform is Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of directories and loop over them you can use `find` in conjunction with a `for` loop:

```
for subdir in $(find path/to/parent/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
        # Do stuff with $subdir i.e:
        echo $subdir
done
```

Here `find` is limited to directories with `-type d`, and `-maxdepth 1` will only give the initial subdirectories, and not the child directories of the subdirectories.

To put your initial code within this loop:

```
START_DIR=$(pwd)
# Loop over all directories
for subdir in $(find path/to/parent/dir -mathdepth 1 -type d); do
      # Get the base name, for the pdf naming
      subdir_base=$(basedir $subdir);

      cd subdir;

      for i in *.jpg; do 
          num=`expr match "$i" '\([0-9]\+\).*'`;
          padded=`printf "%03d" $num`; mv -v "$i" "${i/$num/$padded}";
      done

      FILES=$( find . -type f -name "*jpg" | cut -d/ -f 2)
      mkdir temp && cd temp 

      for file in $FILES; do 
           BASE=$(echo $file | sed 's/.jpg//g');
           convert ../$BASE.jpg $BASE.pdf; 
      done && 
      pdftk *pdf cat output ../../pdffolder/$subdir_base.pdf && 
      cd ..
      rm -rf temp
      cd $START_DIR;
 done;
```